# Adding hyperlink to a matched string in pdf

Tags: python

I am having a PDF containing plain text. I have to search for a particular string and add a hyperlink to the matched string. I tried regular expression to find the string but struggling to add a hyperlink to that string. Is it possible to add a link to a PDF file or should change the file format? And how that can be done.

Comment: It is done by adding a PDF hyperlink annotation that those active region is the area on the page where the text appears. How you do this depends on the library. At this time I can't give an example but this might  help you search for how to do it.

Comment: @DanD. Thanks a lot. I'll try.